# how to solve js issue after installing the ssl on my business listing site

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the ssl in https://search-me.info/ , but after ssl installation js is not working in some places , please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to `mixed-content` being blocked by your browser. This means that some of your resources (like js scripts) are loaded over `http` instead of `https`.

Make sure that all your scripts and resources are loaded over https and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all script tag should not be included in form of

*http://host_url/script_name*

**OR**

*https://host_url/script_name*

rather you can use

**//host_url/script_name**

if will do the fix